# Angular 7 CORS giving error and data at same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, cors

My application front end is in angular 7 and backend is in ndoejs (express). I am using `cors` module in nodejs server.js like this.

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors());
```

When i am making api call from front end i can see one more call of `OPTIONS` after searching some solutions i found that `OPTIONS` is automatic call in case of cors calls.

In my case both hits are there one is of OPTIONS and second is of POST. OPTIONS hit returning `204 no content` and POST hit is returning expected data but at the same time i am getting this error in my browser.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:2233/api/question' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My code is in try catch and its going in catch after api call but in network tab data is visible in api response.

Any idea whats wrong??

**EDIT**

Response headers on OPTIONS call

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, 
Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2019 11:49:11 GMT
ETag: W/"4-Yf+Bwwqjx254r+pisuO9HfpJ6FQ"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Response headers on POST call

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 64
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2019 11:23:06 GMT
ETag: W/"40-q2QpyVWh4SyAq38SeUHizD/aESI"
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Comment: it's a CORS error ... network tab shows the response, because the browser does get the response, but the response isn't available to javascript - that's how CORS works - it is odd that the OPTIONS preflight passes, but the POST doesn't - perhaps you're *doing something wrong™* in your code

Comment: if you inspect the POST request, what response headers are there? specifically, the CORS `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers = I guess also, the response headers for OPTIONS would be good to see (edit the question, don't put them in a comment)

Comment: @JaromandaX you can check the response headers now

Comment: The POST has no CORS response headers - you've configured something incorrectly

Comment: @JaromandaX maybe but i am getting correct data in response of POST call

Comment: @JaromandaX Any idea how to fix it??

Comment: yes, you are, that's how CORS works

Comment: There all options are there in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding`

Comment: No they aren't - you posted `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization`

Comment: In my server configutation i did all this when i am getting response its showing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization`

Comment: if you truly just use `app.use(cors());` then it should just work

Comment: @JaromandaX fixed something now response headers are changed

Comment: still no CORS headers on the POST response - looks like you're still doing something wrong in code you wont show

Comment: Earlier i was using `app.use(cors())` that was not working now i am setting cors manually

Comment: `app.use(cors())` works fine for me :p ... odd that your `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` is `GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH` ... with spaces, no HEAD or DELETE ... out of the box, I get `GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE` - it's almost like the responses you're getting are manually created by you

Comment: i tried sending response headers manually in my API response and its working that way. Not sure why its not working with generic `app.use` function or `cors()`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for all your efforts i got the solution. Posted in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Thanks a ton to [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) for telling me the actual issue.

Actually issue was not getting cors response header in POST call and after googling some problems i came to know the problem that i was adding `cors()` in my application after defining api routes and after shifting `cors()` before routes solved the problem.